# Linking to a specific place on an external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay, In HTML, preferably 5, is there a way to set a link to take the user to a specific place on an external? I know I can link to an anchor

```
<a href="#blahblah"> goes to <a name="blahblah">
```

but what i need to to act as if my anchor is on someone else's page, where I cannot insert an anchor. Help me out?

Comment: Does the location on the other page have an ID where you want to link to? If not, then no.

Comment: You should simply be able to put the full external url + anchor to get to where you want. Ex: `http://google.com/#links`

Comment: Google is your friend...this question has been asked a ton of times if you simply google your question!

Comment: You can't link to specific location in external page, which is under a different domain. You'll have to ask the owner of the other site to add an anchor, or use server side code to read the contents of the page, parse them yourself, and send back to the client with the desired anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just use the hash after your root URL, like so:

`<a href="myotherpage.html#myanchor"></a>`

or

`<a href="myotherpage/#myanchor"></a>`

However, if there is no anchor on the other page or you aren't in control of that page, then I'm afraid there is not a way to do that.

Comment: `<a href="myotherpage.html#myanchor"></a>`

Comment: Thanks for that. If the URL is served without the extension, you would use a trailing slash followed by your anchor dest.

Comment: Actually, `myotherpage/#myanchor` would anchor to the default page in the `myotherpage` directory (commonly the same as `myotherpage/index.html#myanchor`). If you are referring to the extensionless myotherpage, it would be `myotherpage#myanchor`

Comment: @RobertMcKee the trailing slash works with an extension or without. ```<a href="myotherpage.html/#myanchor">``` works. ```myotherpage/#myanchor``` would be used if your url was something like ```mywebsite.com/my-post/``` where the filename extensions arent included in the URL

Comment: "someone else's page, where I cannot insert an anchor" - the answer is correct, but useless for OP

Comment: Then I guess the answer is a big ol' fat no.

Comment: True, see my comment on the question

Comment: @la1ch3 The extension (.html) doesn't matter, but when you say `myotherpage/#myanchor`, `myotherpage` refers to a directory, not a page.  The page that will get loaded is actually `myotherpage/index.html#myanchor`.  If `myotherpage/#myanchor` is loading your `myotherpage.html` page, it is likely because you have a redirect on your server set up to remove trailing slashes from your URLs, or another redirect that is "fixing" it for you.